# Adding legend to a single plot of multiple linear regression plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, linear-regression, legend

I plotted two ggplots from two different datasets in one single plot. plots are simple linear regression. I want to add legend both for lines and dots in the plot with different colours. How can I do that? The code I used for plot is as below. But, I failed to add a desirable legend to that.

```
ggplot() + 
     geom_point(aes(x = Time_1, y = value1)) +
     geom_point(aes(x = Time_2, y = value2)) +
     geom_line(aes(x = Time_1, y = predict(reg, newdata = dataset)))+
     geom_line(aes(x = Time_Month.x, y = predict(regressor, newdata = training_set)))+ 
     ggtitle('Two plots in a single plot')
```

Answer (score 2):

ggplot2 adds legends automatically if it has groups within the data. Your original code provides the minimum amount of information to ggplot(), basically enough for it to work but not enough to create a legend.

Since your data comes from two different objects due to the two different regressions, then it looks like all you need in this case is to add the 'color = "INSERT COLOR NAME"' argument to each geom_point() and each geom_line().  Using R's built-in mtcars data set for example, what you have is similar to

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = wt)) + ggtitle("Example Graph")
```

[Graph without Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEwVp.png)

And what you want can be obtained by using something similar to,

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, color = "blue")) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = wt, color = "green")) + ggtitle("Example Graph")
```

[Graph with Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oMTQ.png)

Which would seem to translate to

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_point(aes(x = Time_1, y = value1, color = "blue")) +
 geom_point(aes(x = Time_2, y = value2, color = "green")) +
 geom_line(aes(x = Time_1, y = predict(reg, newdata = dataset), color = "red"))+
 geom_line(aes(x = Time_Month.x, y = predict(regressor, newdata = training_set), color = "yellow"))+ 
 ggtitle('Two plots in a single plot')
```

You could also use the size, shape, or alpha arguments inside of aes() to differentiate the different series.

Comment: I tried this but it does not create a legend, just making plot colourful. I need a legent inside my plot

Comment: @R_mad It sounds like you are asking for a legend within the bounds of the plot (as opposed to a legend like the one provided in my example plot "Graph with Legend").  If that is the case, then look into using + theme(), there are lots of arguments for legends within the theme() function.

Comment: @R_mad If instead you are saying that it didn't create a legend at all, even with the color = argument. Then the next step would be to provide a portion of your data so that someone could replicate your exact set-up.